# SAS Renaming Columns

Tags: statistics, sas

beginner SAS user here. Trying to rename column variables from NHANES data, but the code that I am using is registering wrong. The column names are long and drawn out so its been nearly impossible for me to try to recode them into a simpler format. Example and code down below, any assistance is greatly appreciated! For example, I'm trying to get Respondent sequence number to be renamed as ID, but SAS is having issues with the spaces between the original name if that makes sense.

```
data NHANES.Combined;
set NHANES.Combined;
rename Respondent sequence number = ID; run;
```

[Image of Data Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLnhW.png)

Comment: You have to put equal signs between each pair of names.  The RENAME statement in your code has 4 names but only 1 equal sign.

Comment: The photograph you showed seems to be showing the LABELS on the variables.  Change your VIEWTABLE options to show the variable NAMES instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the names in the RENAME statement, not the labels you are looking at in the VIEWTABLE window.  If you actually have a name with spaces in it (which you will not with NHANES data) then use a name literal in the code so SAS can parse out what parts of the command line represent the variable names.

```
 rename 'non standard name'n = standard_name ;
```

Run PROC CONTENTS on your dataset to see the variable names and their attributes (TYPE, LENGTH, FORMAT, LABEL).